# Create Stack of different types

Tags: c#

My main problem is that I have four enums:

```
public enum Main : int { Loading = 0, Main, PageSelect, Achievements, Play, Settings, Store }
public enum Play : int { DarkLayer = 0, Main, AddCharacter, AddBackground, AddEffect, TakePhoto, VideoRecord, AddFilter, VideoSave}
public enum Settings : int { Main = 0, Tutorial, ParentalControl } 
public enum Store : int { Main = 0, Pages, AllBookUnlocked, InsertCode, ConectionFailed, ErrorCode, TransactionFailed, BoughtPage, Send }
```

Each one represent the screens of my app and I use them to switch between the screens. My problem is that I need to create a history to go back, but since the enums have different types (Main, Play, Settings and Store) I do not know how to store them in a single history.

For example, if I am in the Main.Main screen and I go to Play.Main I would need to store both in a kind of stack to go back to Main.Main. I do not know if it is possible to do (I do not think so) but I just want to make sure.

Comment: `new Stack<Enum>()`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var stack = new Stack<Enum>();
stack.Push(Main.PageSelect);
var value = stack.Pop();
if (value is Main)
{
    Main page = (Main)value;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Enigmativity it works perfect =D

Answer (score -1):

Create one more **enum** to store all your needed enums:

```
public enum MyEnums : int { Main = 0, Play, Settings, Store }
```

Then you can create a `Stack` like this:

```
var stack = new Stack<Tuple<MyEnums, int>>();
stack.Add(new Tuple<MyEnums, int>(MyEnums.Main, Main.PageSelect)); // This will be casted to int
var tuple = stack.Pop();
switch(tuple.Item1)
{
    case MyEnums.Main:
    var ourPage = (Main) tuple.Item2; // Cast back to an appropriate enum
    return RedirectToAction(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can not use Tuple because I am using Unity and it does not include them.

Comment: @Nestoraj I guess you can try Enigmativity's answer and see if it works for you then.